# Instance variables in partial view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two controllers **Players** and **Teams**

I want to render a partial view from a team view that belongs to the `Players_controller`. I have the problem that I can't reach the instance variables from the `Players_controller`.

Do I need to define these variables again in my `Team_controller`?

Comment: are players and teams related via ActiveRecord?

Comment: Can you show a bit of code? The controller action and views would help.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [this link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html). I think what you are looking for is either

```
<%= render :partial => "customer", :object => @new_customer %>
```

or something like

```
<%= render :partial => "form", :locals => { :zone => @zone } %>
```

Comment: I made a change to your answer before realizing that I just wasn't aware of the `:object` option when rendering partials.  I reverted the change, sorry about that.  And thanks for teaching me something new. :)